# What could be the maximum value of Determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant

Let $X=[x_{i,j}] \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers. Recall that $$ \det (X) = \sum _{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sign} (\sigma)\prod_{i =1}^{n} x_{i,\sigma{(i)}}  $$

We assume that for every $i,j$, $|x_{i,j}|\leq p$.

**My attempt :** From the above formula, it appears that $|\det (X)| \le n! \times p^{n}$.

Does there exist a better bound ?

Comment: Hint: The determinant is the (signed) measure (area/volume/etc.) of the n-[parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) which your matrix transforms a unit n-cube into.  How can the measure of this parallelepiped be maximized while minimizing p?

Comment: You need to somehow constrain the $x$'s. Do we assume $x\le p$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That is implicit in p's definition: It's the maximum.

Comment: @Kevin: no, $p$ is an external constant.

Comment: @sssss: are you serious ? If the $x$ are unbounded, the upper bound is $\infty$, and this is tight.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: "From the above it formula it appears that **let p be a max value in matrix X** then..."

Comment: @Kevin: this hypothesis does not belong to the question and is not accepted as a bound on $x$ by the OP himself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I'm *quoting* from the question.  What do you mean by it "does not belong to the question"?

Comment: @Kevin: you are quoting form the OP's attempt, not from the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Obviously OP is willing to accept bounds in terms of p, given that they attempted to construct one.  It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I am assuming that let $p$ be the maximum value in input array.

Comment: @Kevin: if the OP doesn't state an explicit bounding criterion on the matrix (such as a maximum norm), the question has a trivial answer. And the answer will differ with different criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; $|\det(X)|\leq n^{n/2}p^n$. cf. Hadamard matrices

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Hadamard_conjecture

Comment: I think this is the link you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality

Comment: @Wintermute , you are right; I gave another link to study the case of equality.